# Zip compress without root folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plsql, zip, dbms-scheduler

My problem is that I have to generate a zip file using the linux zip console command. My command is as follows:

```
zip -r /folder1/folder2/EXP_45.zip /folder1/folder2/EXP_45/
```

That returns a correct zip only that includes the root folders I want:

***Returns***

EXP_45.zip

-folder1

--folder2

---EXP_45

...

***I want***

EXP_45.zip

-EXP_45

...

EXP_45 is a folder that can contain files and folders and they must be present in the zip. I just want the tree structure to start with the EXP_45 folder.

Is there any solution?

The reason why I need it to be a single command is that it is an action of a job in a PL SQL function like:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( 
    JOB_NAME=>'compress_files',       --- job name 
    JOB_ACTION=>'/usr/bin/zip',    --- executable file with path 
    JOB_TYPE=>'executable',        -----   job type
    NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS=>4,  --  parameters in numbers                   
    AUTO_DROP =>false,
    CREDENTIAL_NAME=>'credentials'   -- give credentials name which you have created before "credintial"
    );

dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',1,'-r');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',2,'-m');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',3,'/folder1/folder2/EXP_45.zip');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',4,'/folder1/folder2/EXP_45/');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('compress_files');
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem using zip but I have found it using jar. The command would be:

```
jar cMf /folder1/folder2/EXP_45.zip -C /folder1/folder2/EXP_45 .
```

Also, the solution using a job in pl sql in case it works for someone would be:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( 
    JOB_NAME=>'compress_files',       --- job name 
    JOB_ACTION=>'/usr/bin/jar',    --- executable file with path 
    JOB_TYPE=>'executable',        -----   job type
    NUMBER_OF_ARGUMENTS=>5,  --  parameters in numbers                   
    AUTO_DROP =>false,
    CREDENTIAL_NAME=>'credentials'   -- give credentials name which you have created before "credintial"
    );

dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',1,'cMf');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',2,'/folder1/folder2/EXP_45.zip');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',3,'-C');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',4,'/folder1/folder2/EXP_45');
dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('compress_files',5,'.');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('compress_files');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `-j` (or `--junk-paths`) option when you are creating the zip file. Below is from the zip man page.

```
   -j
   --junk-paths
          Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. 
          By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).
```

**Update following Question Clarification**

Why not put the equivalent to the code below in a shell script & get the SQL function to invoke that? You just need to pass the directory name to cd into and the name of the output zip.

```
cd folder1/folder2
zip -r /tmp/EXP_45.zip EXP_45
```

Comment: My problem is that the EXP_45 folder may contain other folders and I need that structure to remain. I want store folders, but the structure must starts at EXP_45.

Comment: Not obvious that was what you wanted in the original question. Would this work ? `cd folder1/folder2; zip -r /tmp/EXP_45.zip EXP_45`

Comment: It doesn't work, it has to be in a single command for the function I have.

Comment: Can you give us more details on how exactly you are invoking zip. What language are you working with? That will help us understand the restrictions you are working under.

Comment: I've updated the information. And thanks for the answers :)

Comment: I have tried it in 2 ways: with 2 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB, one for the cd and one for zip, and it hasn't gone since each execution is independent, and with a single DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB with action cd and arguments "/folder1/folder2; zip EXP_45.zip EXP_45" and it has not given an error but it has only executed the cd and the zip hasn't

Comment: I can't think why a script with two lines would only execute the first line. As far as the scheduler is concerned JOB_ACTION  is just an executable. You have set the execute bit on the script?  Try getting the script to output some logging to a temporary file to see what it is doing. Alsio, how do you know it did the `cd `part and not the `zip` part?

Comment: I think it only runs the cd part because if I put an incorrect path in the first part it gives an error, but if I put it in the second part it doesn't. For example: '/folderError/cd /folder1/folder2; zip EXP_45.zip EXP_45' fails, but '/usr/bin/cd /folder1/folder2; /folderError/zip EXP_45.zip EXP_45' don't